# how to set a price rule for two specific individual products in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have to create a shopping cart price rule for two specific products so that when I add these two products I got the discount on the total price.

I tried many conditions in the condition tab but it didn't happening. this is my condition tab

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If total quantity  is  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
    SKU  is one of  zol_b_lrg, sport_b_lrg
    Frequently is 100
```

Now what is wrong with these condition.
I select the `Fixed amount discount for whole cart` from the `Apply` tab and set the value in the next tab eg 10

But nothing is happening. Help me with this please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to pick the `"is one of"` operator instead, and create the conditions under the `Action` tab.

It's uncertain for me still why the product conditions can't be on the `Conditions` tab, alas.

Comment: oops.. Sorry for the typo, it is `is one of` instead of `is`
but its not working either

Comment: What happens if you register those conditions in the `Actions` tab ?

Comment: I didn't create any conditions in the action tab.

Comment: Try adding the conditions there. Also, after you set the rule working, I think your rule is going to be applied for 2 items of the same product.

Comment: ok. let me try over there also. lets see if something happens or not, I will notify you afterwards

Comment: I still don't know how to explain the reasoning behind conditions/action tabs, but that's an easy workaround =)

Comment: yeah me too don't understand what is the reason behind this, Hope will be figure out someday

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12644/discussion-between-waseem-and-niloct)